# public final fields vs getters/setters?

Tags: java

Having this code:

```
public class MouseEvent extends Event {

    private int x, y;
    private boolean dragged;

    public MouseEvent(int x, int y, boolean dragged) {
        super(Event.TYPE.MOUSE_MOVED);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dragged = dragged;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

i've been told, "Why whould you use accessors and not just public final fields?" which confused me a lot.

What exactly am i missing here? I mean, those are absolutely different consepts.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

> those are absolutely different consepts.

No, they are not absolutely different.

They are two ways to accomplish the same goal: exposing properties of your object.

```
int x = myMouseEvent.getX() ;
```

…has the same effect as…

```
int x = myMouseEvent.x ;
```

## Details

Since there is no way to reassign an object to any of your three class member fields, and there are no other complexities, then providing getter methods has the exact same effect as directly accessing public final members.

Either way, if you do intend for the member variables to never be reassigned to alternate objects, then you should enforce and document that intention by marking the vars as `final`. That means they are not actually variables, as their contents (a reference to a particular object) never varies for the life of that object.

As for defining accessor getter methods, that is only helpful if you now or later might return something other than simply the contained object reference. For example, if you need security checks or need to calculate a result or need to generate a formatted response, then you need a getter method in which to write such code.

Another benefit of getter/setter methods in Java is that your object can be treated as a [JavaBean](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) for the purpose of exposing properties without the bother of building a `BeanInfo`. That can be convenient in situations such as displaying your objects in a [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/components/components-grid.html) widget in a [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web app.

Comment: can you please provide the answer with some code samples to clear things up a little bit?